# How to transfer multiple rows from one tab to another based on matching cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two tabs in my sheet -- "Current" and "Futures".

Current is everything that has a date of TODAY.  Futures are inputted well in advance, but when that date arrives (meaning -- input an order to take place on 3/7 on 3/1, then 3/7 arrives), I want the rows (only columns A to L) with MATCHING dates to move from FUTURES to CURRENT and append to the first blank cell in column A.

The rows should append, then be removed from FUTURES.

I have a "=TODAY" in cell Q1 of daily, and am matching column A of FUTURES to that.

My current script does not seem to make any action when I run it.

```
function copyIfMatched() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1eRO-30eIZamB5sjBp-Mz2QMKCfGxV037MQO8nS7G7AI");
  var futures = ss.getSheetByName("Futures");
  var daily = ss.getSheetByName("Daily");
  
  var futuresData = futures.getRange("A3:L" + futures.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var dailyMatchValue = daily.getRange("Q1").getValue();
  var dailyData = daily.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  for (var i = futuresData.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (futuresData[i][0] === dailyMatchValue) {
      dailyData.push(futuresData[i].slice(0, 12));
      futures.deleteRow(i + 3);
    }
  }
  
  daily.getDataRange().clearContent();
  daily.getRange(1, 1, dailyData.length, dailyData[0].length).setValues(dailyData);
}
```

The

Any advice as to what might be off?

I have a test sheet here, with a sample of the workflow.

There are two tabs, Daily & Futures - There is a date in Cell Q1 on Daily.  If that cell matches any value in COLUMN A of FUTURES, that row on FUTURES should be MOVED to Daily.  In other words, if the date matches, add it to the DAILY tab and remove it from the FUTURES:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xWzwCwr052iHcyukirSm6wbq_WNFOoDR9ZqjOIfY85Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot your question. Can I ask you about the detail of `I thought this would work, but having trouble --`? And, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: Yes, apologies will update my question now

Comment: Hoping that helps a little, I added in two tabs. Now you can see what DAILY and FUTURES should look like before and after the script takes place.  I'm trying to move any rows where COLUMN A in FUTURES matches the date in Q1 on Daily.  The movement should be from DAILY to FUTURES and should be columns A to L on any of the rows with a matching value.  Those rows should append to the first blank cell in COL A of DAILY and they should then be removed from FUTURES. Does this help at all?

Comment: Thank you for replying. How do you want do abuot "Green" of column "Q"? You just want to copy the values from the specific rows of "A:L" in "Futures" sheet to the range of "A3:L" in "Daily" sheet? And also, how do you want to do about the background color of cells of both sheets? Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your expected situation. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: My apologies, I'm not explaining it well. No need to worry about the background color or the "Green" column, it would just be columns A to L that I'm trying to move the data over, then the row can be deleted.  Stuck as to why I'm not seeing any movement at all with my current script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy the values from the specific rows of "A:L" in "Futures" sheet to the range of "A3:L" in "Daily" sheet by checking the values of column "A".
- From your reply of `No need to worry about the background color or the "Green" column, it would just be columns A to L that I'm trying to move the data over, then the row can be deleted.`, you want to just move the specific rows.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

I thought that the reason for your current issue might be due to the method for comparing the date values. So, in this sample script, in order to compare the value of date, as an approach, it is compared as a string value. Of course, I think that the date object can be also used. But, in that case, it is required to modify the below script. Please be careful about this.

#### Sample script:

```js
function copyIfMatched() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1eRO-30eIZamB5sjBp-Mz2QMKCfGxV037MQO8nS7G7AI");
  var futures = ss.getSheetByName("Futures");
  var daily = ss.getSheetByName("Daily");

  // I modified the below script.
  var dailyMatchValue = daily.getRange("Q1").getDisplayValue();
  var range1 = futures.getRange("A3:L" + futures.getLastRow());
  var futuresData2 = range1.getDisplayValues();
  var { newValues, oldValues } = range1.getValues().reduce((o, r, i) => (o[futuresData2[i][0] == dailyMatchValue ? "newValues" : "oldValues"].push(r), o), { newValues: [], oldValues: [] });
  if (newValues.length == 0) return;

  // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639
  Object.prototype.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom = function (columnNumber, offsetRow = 1) {
    const search = this.getRange(offsetRow, columnNumber, this.getMaxRows()).createTextFinder(".").useRegularExpression(true).findPrevious();
    return search ? search.getRow() : offsetRow;
  };

  daily.getRange(daily.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(1) + 1, 1, newValues.length, newValues[0].length).setValues(newValues);
  range1.clearContent().offset(0, 0, oldValues.length, oldValues[0].length).setValues(oldValues);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are copied from the "Futures" sheet to the "Daily" sheet by checking the values of column "A". In this case, the moved values are appended to the "Daily" sheet.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)

Comment: Wow amazing, it is incredibly fast too. This is the perfect solution for this question. amazing

Comment: Can't thank you enough, learning so much from you. I'm deep into the printer issue, trying a million different things pushing to a PDF first, setting Google Sheet print settings, etc.. nothing yet but will keep you posted if i figure out anything

Comment: @Anthony Madle Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question by your cooperation. Thank you, too.